# Objective C: Different behavior variables in header (.h) file vs. implementation (.m) file

Tags: objective-c

Could someone please explain the Objective-C difference between `myString` and `anotherString` in the following snippet:

```
   // In .h file
   @interface MyClass : NSObject {
 NSString* myString;
   }
   @end

   // In .m file
   @interface MyClass ()
   NSString* anotherString;
   @end

   @implementation MyClass
   //...
   @end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the .h file, you declare an instance variable. Each object will have a different one.

In the implementation file, you declare a global variable (the fact it's in a category does not change anything).
So the value of that variable will be the same, no matter the object's instance.

Note that this is often useful to simulate class variables, but with the `static` keyword, so the variable is only available from the implementation file.

Answer (score 2):

In the .m file, the `@interface MyClass()` is actually a category, not a proper interface declaration. The difference is that categories can *not* add instance variables, only methods.